# Is there a configuration that let's me run the desktop from 9.10?

Tags: gnome, 9.10, desktop-environments

Just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and it runs so slow, even with all effects and services turned off. I put in Ubuntu 9.10 on my computer the other day and it runs like a dream. I even find Ubuntu 9.10 more visually appealing than 10.04 onwards. I also like the extra effects that you can make in appearance, they just look better.

My question is:

**- Is there an existing distribution (or a way to create one) based on GNOME 2.x that has the latest security updates, a software for handling drivers like jockey-gtk, and the latest Ubuntu repositories?**

I have tried to use Debian Squeeze, which is close to what I want, but my main criticisms are that the repositories are out-of-date and there is no simple application for installing proprietary drivers like jockey-gtk in Ubuntu (which I've tried running on Debian with little success).

I'd really appreciate anything you can tell me to help me achieve this, but please don't suggest GNOME fallback session. It still runs very slowly (and doesn't look the same). I'm not here to provoke anybody, it is just the environment I work best in.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 uses the latest version of Gnome 2. By the way, it is perfectly possible to make Gnome Panel 3 look identical to Gnome Panel 2. (Often referred to as Ubuntu Classic, Gnome Classic or Gnome Fallback. It's the same program)

Comment: Did you try Unity 2D in Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no official or unofficial Ubuntu based distributions based on such an old version of Ubuntu.

Without knowing more about your PC, my suggestion would be to use a more lighter version of Ubuntu that both combine the same traditional gnome-2 workflow that you are used to.

Lubuntu and Xubuntu are the main official distros I would warmly recommend.

If you are looking for "visual effects" - then Xubuntu together with its own compositor is your best bet.

Both distros uses the same version of Jockey as Unity based Ubuntu.

If you really want to use a Gnome2 based interface - stick to 10.04.  It is the LTS and as such will receive security updates upto April 2013.

Comment: I have 1.8GHZ AMD Sempron, 512MB RAM, an old ATI Radeon.
So there is nothing based on old GNOME? What a shame.
Those were the days when Ubuntu cared about performance.

Comment: From Ubuntu 7.04-9.10, you didn't need a fast computer. Now with every subsequent release of Ubuntu you need a more powerful computer. I think the solution is to install 9.10 and use .deb files for the rest of my life.

Comment: I'm using 10.04 on a similar spec laptop as you.  It runs absolutely great - very similar to what I remember to 9.10.

Comment: Hmm, it didn't run that well for me. Everything was slow, and it was a clean install too. Having two tabs on Firefox seemed to really slow things down :( well, thank you for your advice. I think I will stick to Debian Unstable.